# How does the piping in this command ultimately achieve to kill the process?

Tags: bash, command-line, process, pipe, kill

I have seen the following line in a bash script for killing a process(in this case started with the command `loadgen`):

```
ps xww | grep -i "loadgen" | grep "PATTERNMATCH_FACT.xml" | cut -c1-5 | xargs -i kill {} 2>/dev/null
```

I would like to understand the reason for piping after the two grep's in the command above.

The way the `loadgen` command is started is the following. It's a part of the startup script.

```
./loadgen -XMLFile ${DEMODIR}/bam-103-pattern-match/data/PATTERNMATCH_FACT.xml -duration 0 -frequency 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ps xww` gives the following output

```
...
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 init [2]
 1804 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
...
```

After the two `grep`'s it pipes the output to `cut`. This command cuts the character 1-5 out of the output. In the output above it whould be the PID's:

```
    1
 1804
```

This is piped to `xargs`. Xargs builds commands that look like this:

```
kill 1
kill 1804
```

and executes them. `2>/dev/null` means that all error messages are sent to the pseudo device `/dev/null`.

So your command kills every process that is `grep`ed out of the `ps` command.

Or see [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ps%20xww%20%7C%20grep%20-i%20%22loadgen%22%20%7C%20grep%20%22PATTERNMATCH_FACT.xml%22%20%7C%20cut%20-c1-5%20%7C%20xargs%20-i%20kill%20%7B%7D%202%3E/dev/null).

Comment: can you please explain the `2>/dev/null` part? I don't get how errors are prevented. What errors are we talking about here?

Comment: Errors of shell commands are always written to channel 2. `2>/dev/null` means that this channel is redirected to /dev/null, which is a pseudo device. Errors like when no process with the given PID is found. The `2>/dev/null` part is not needed, its just cosmetics.

Comment: can you please explain the `xargs -i kill {}` part? Especially the `{}` part of it? Why is that needed?

Comment: `xargs` is a tool to expand its arguments into a commands list.  Everything piped into `xargs` is considered a list to expand, and `{}` is the placeholder for 'list item here'.  So sending to `... | xargs kill {}` means "for every thing in this list, use the command `kill _____`, and fill in the blank with the list entry.

Comment: `kill` errors are not prevented. They happen as usual. `2>/dev/null` just discards the actual error messages.

Comment: actually xargs will batch the commands into groups of 50 or so, so it runs `kill 1 1804`, and if there were more than 50 PIDs, it would execute more batches.   This is why it can be beneficial to do `ls | xarg -iz rm z` instead of deleting files one by one.